# Does mvc4 model object encapsulate sql?

Tags: sql, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have used asp.net web forms for the last four years. I am trying to familiarise myself with mvc4. Do you put sql code in the model if you are not using an orm like entity framework. For example, if you have a domain object (model class) called person then would you have functions like: person.select, person.update, person.delete.

I am confused because i thought that mvc4 was for the user interface so it doesn't seem right putting sql statements in the model.

I have read plenty of questions on here about mvc4 today but i have not found a specific answer

Comment: Your Model is just POCO classes, all of the leg work is done by the controller. The Controller populates the Model with data for use in the View.

Comment: My opinion is that the best place to write sql code is in a stored procedure and that your controller simply calls these sp's.

Comment: @DanBracuk Yes and No. If you aren't using an ORM then definitely use stored procs. It probably isn't great practice having your Controller calling the stored procs directly though. Some kind of data layer or Repository should really be used

Answer (score 1):

Any CRUD functions are executed from the controller level. You may have a Data Access Layer or Repository abstracting those away but the calls to those functions will be Controller level.

If data needs passed to the view, that data is put into a view model. The view model is then passed to the view to be consumed. The view can only access the data in that model. When you want to update something, you make a call back to the Controllers Update action, the Controller can then handle it from there.

The Model itself is just a `POCO (Plain Old CLR Object)` which will not have any methods. The `@Html`and `@Ajax` helpers are useful for quickly accessing the Controller Actions. The Ajax ones can return partial views which will assist with updating data on screen without post backs.

There is a pretty good MVC4 (free) video tutorial, split up into small segments so you can easily find the bit you need. [Take a look at it here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/pluralsight-building-applications-with-aspnet-mvc-4)

Comment: Thanks +1. Is it fair to say that the model is a domain object/data transfer object?

Comment: There will most likely be 2 types of Model. Domain Models returned from your business logic and View Models which really only get used between the Controller and View. You could pass a Domain Model to a View but if your needs were more complex than a single Entity or Result Set, you would need to pass all the required data into a View Model and then send that on to the View.